# Hitting Query Limit in Google Distance Matrix API on R

Tags: r, google-maps, distance, google-distancematrix-api

I have a list of 36 locations for which I have to get a distance matrix from each location to every other location, i.e. a 36x36 matrix. Using help from other questions on this topic on this forum, I was able to put together a basic code (demonstrated with four locations only) as follows:

```
library(googleway)
library(plyr)
key <- "VALID KEY" #removed for security reasons
districts <- c("Attock, Pakistan", 
           "Bahawalnagar, Pakistan", 
           "Bahawalpur, Pakistan",
           "Bhakkar, Pakistan")

#Calculate pairwise distance between each location
lst <- google_distance(origins=districts, destinations=districts, key=key)

res.lst <- list() 

lst_elements <- for (i in 1:length(districts)) {
e.row <- rbind(cbind(districts[i], distance_destinations(lst), 
distance_elements(lst)[[i]][['distance']]))
res.lst[[i]] <- e.row
}

# view results as list
res.lst

# combine each element of list into a dataframe. 
res.df <- ldply(res.lst, rbind)

#give names to columns
colnames(res.df) <- c("origin", "destination", "dist.km", "dist.m")

#Display result    
res.df
```

This code works fine for small number of queries; i.e. if locations are few e.g. 5 at a time. For anything larger, I get a "Over-Query-Limit" error with the message: "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API" even though I have not reached the 2500 limit. I also signed up for 'Pay-as-you-use' billing option but I continue to get the same error. I wonder if this is an issue of how many requests are being sent per second (i.e. the rate)? And if so, can I modify my code to address this? Even without an API key, this code does not ask for more than 2500 queries so I should be able to do it but I'm stumped how to resolve this even with billing enabled.

Comment: Some other people responding on this issue have suggested breaking down the list of locations into smaller chunks and running the code that way to avoid hitting the rate limit. However, since I need a pairwise distance matrix of each location with every other location, I also can't think of a way to break it down into smaller chunks. Any suggestions on that will be appreciated too!

Comment: I gave an answer from the docs earlier (deleted now) but I wanted to preserve this comment you made: "According to my Google API product dashboard, I have the following quotas: Elements per day 100,000 (2,500 free) Elements per 100 seconds 10,000 Elements per 100 seconds per user Unlimited " . OK so at this point I'd say it's a customer service issue for Google, so you should reach out to them.

Answer (score 1):

The free quota is 2500 **elements**.

> Each query sent to the Distance Matrix API is limited by the number of allowed **elements**, **where the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements**.
>
> **Standard Usage Limits**
>   **Users of the standard API:**
>
> 2,500 free elements per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
>   Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request.

a 36x36 request would be 1296 elements.  After 2 you would be out of quota.

Comment: Yes, but I only need to run this once i.e. get the 1296 elements and that's it. I'm trying to figure out how to break it down into smaller chunks; maybe by having smaller origins list and a full destinations list (i.e. have only four locations in origins and all 36 in destinations) and run the google_distance command several times over. Perhaps that might solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this issue; I was able to resolve it by using a while loop. Since I was well under the 2500 query limit, this was a rate problem rather than a query limit being reached problem. With a while loop, I broke the locations into chunks (running distance queries for 2x36 at a time) and looping over the entire data to get the 36x36 I needed.